# How to Run Vim Commands When Opening File

Tags: vim

How can I have vim commands at the top of a file, like the shebang convention? An example is best:

```py
#/usr/bin/env python3

#v set textwidth=70

print("Hello")
```

In this example, Vim would look for a comment starting with `#v`, and execute the following command.

TL;DR: how can I make Vim run specific commands by opening a file, not linked to a file type, and not by adding lines to my `init.vim`? Plugins are also an option.

Comment: You said plugins are an option. Do you mean that you would be ok with writing your commands in a file, then using `:source your_filename_here` in vim to run the commands? Or you want a these commands to run every time you open vim?

Comment: No, I meant I would use a plugin that runs commands from specially formatted comments in a file that Vim opens.

Comment: Yes, I would like the commands to run every time I open Vim with a specific file.

Comment: Why do you need the distinction of specially formatted comment-commands as opposed to just having a vimscript file that runs every time you open vim?

Comment: Because different files would have different commands. The concept is similar to Pylint's error ignore comments: `# pylint: disable=C0321`. Some files you need to set x and y settings, others z and w.

Comment: Apologies for my confusion, I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do. So your idea is you have a file `temp.txt` that contains a mix of text and vimscript functions and when you do `vim temp.txt`, you want for vim to open this file to edit AND for vim to also execute the file as a vimscript file? Or another way to put it, you want vimscript code that executes and is associated only with a specific file (e.g. a function `func_a` is automatically executed when `temp.txt` is opened, but not necessarily any other `.txt` files)?

Comment: Yes. The answer below, `modeline`, was exactly what I was looking for. I can put `# vim: set tw=70: #` in my file and it executes when Vim opens the file. Apologies for my somewhat confusing question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
:help modeline
```

Note that adding self-serving modelines to files in a shared project is generally seen as pollution and frowned upon.